# Error running a Java 8 batch with a jdk17

Tags: java, spring, openjdk-17

I'm trying to run a java 8 batch with a jdk17, the project is built with a jre1.8.0_192 and I put the following options in the VM:

> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.locale.providers=JRE,SPI

I get the following error at runtime:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()"
> because "obj" is null     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:561) ~[?:?]   at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
> ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:3.0.10.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.25.RELEASE.jar:4.3.25.RELEASE]

Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: How about putting all your code on the class path (no modules used)? AFAIK the new Java versions are fairly backwards compatible when used that way.

Comment: Spring 4.x is compatible with Java8 not with higher versions, you will need at least Spring 5.3 to be able to safely run JDK17.

Comment: How would you proceed to add all the code on the class path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring 4.3 is compatible with Java 6 to 8, higher versions aren't tested and thus not supported.

For list of Spring versions with the JDK compatibility see the [Spring/JDK Compatibility Matrix](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range).

To run with JDK17 you would need to upgrade to Spring 5.3.